# jScrollPane cutting off bottom of scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

you can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/n8Xgz/19/).

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#scroll').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
});
```

CSS:

```
#scroll {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
}
.jspTrack {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.jspArrowUp, .jspArrowDown {
    background-color: #009933;
    border: 1px solid lightgreen;
}
.jspArrowUp.jspDisabled, .jspArrowDown.jspDisabled {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.jspDrag {
    background-color: #009933;
    border: 1px solid lightgreen;
}
```

Whenever it loads, a quarter of the bottom arrow gets cut off.

Please Help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8Xgz/24/

```
$('.jspTrack').css('height', '166');
$('.jspArrow').css({
    'position':'relative',
    'zIndex':'999',
    'height':'14px'
});
```

Comment: I see it fine on my phone and on my computer. What browser are you using?

Comment: Edited the jsFiddle again and added a z-index. Still no good? If so, I'll take a look tomorrow when I'm on my computer.

Comment: The bottom arrow still looks shorter than the top

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2Blxbue.png
http://i.imgur.com/5U6ZPoL.png

Both arrows are 16px x 16px.